# Question deleted, but answer remains (and I can even interact with it)

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, migration

I hopped into the Delete tools, and saw that this question had been deleted:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308989/i-have-recieved-very-strange-message-from-stackoverflow

> [image]

I thought I had seen it on Meta earlier, so I clicked the link, and saw this:

> [image]

You can see the answer in the answerer's profile, even if not signed in:

> [image]

Heck, I can upvote it if I want:

> [image]

How is a question deleted, but the answer remains?

I can't find the Meta question, but I'm guessing maybe it's some weird case where the question got migrated from SO to Meta, then the migration got rejected, and the question got deleted-but-not-quite?

Comment: Hm, the answer looks normal to me too.

Comment: Yes, looks like [Brad Larson♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) found a way to break the migration mechanics with his mod powers by rushing deletion: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30308989/revisions

Comment: Sure looks like pure moderator abuse to me. Breaking all the things.

Comment: The migration wasn't rejected. I saw it earlier today on meta.

Comment: @mmking Migration was rejected about 30 minutes ago.

Comment: He broke the system!

Comment: @bluefeet I swear I saw the question on meta today. There was a note saying `This post was migrated from stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @mmking It was [on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294621/i-have-recieved-very-strange-message-from-stackoverflow) but was closed making it a rejected migration.

Comment: The post doesn't even have a timeline: `https://www.stackoverflow.com/posts/[id]/timeline`

Comment: Since the scheduled job fixed this already, marking as status-completed.

Comment: @Oded can the scheduled job post new answer and get reputation for fixing the bug?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The question was migrated to meta, and then deleted, along with the answers.

Then [the meta question was closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294621/i-have-recieved-very-strange-message-from-stackoverflow) - this rejects the migration, which unlocks the original and undeletes any answers.

So you get what we have here today.

Eventually, a cleanup script will come along, note that there's an undeleted answer to a deleted question, and quietly delete it.

Note that you can *manually* undelete your answer to an auto-deleted, migrated question if you feel like it - with the same effects. And if you're really unlucky, you can sometimes end up [posting new answers to migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked), which will just sit there looking sad until they're deleted as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did this happened already once/did you already saw such a post OR is this the first time this happens ?

Comment: No, this is not the first time this has happened. It's not exactly *common*, but it's not particularly rare either. As usual, the solution is always more deletion.